# Why don't I see any tree item

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

Visual Studio MFC library in 2015

I've been working on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class#insertitem)

And it's not working for me
I don't see any item
There are many older examples
I think it doesn't work on vc2015 ?

Here is the code

```
void CMFCApplication67Dlg::OnTvnSelchangedTree1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT 
*pResult)
{

// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

TVINSERTSTRUCT tvInsert;
tvInsert.hParent = NULL;
tvInsert.hInsertAfter = NULL;
tvInsert.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
tvInsert.item.pszText = _T("United States");

HTREEITEM hCountry = m_l.InsertItem(&tvInsert);

HTREEITEM hPA = m_l.InsertItem(TVIF_TEXT,
    _T("Pennsylvania"), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, hCountry, NULL);

HTREEITEM hWA = m_l.InsertItem(_T("Washington"),
    0, 0, hCountry, hPA);

m_l.InsertItem(_T("Pittsburgh"), hPA, TVI_SORT);
m_l.InsertItem(_T("Harrisburg"), hPA, TVI_SORT);
m_l.InsertItem(_T("Altoona"), hPA, TVI_SORT);

m_l.InsertItem(_T("Seattle"), hWA, TVI_SORT);
m_l.InsertItem(_T("Kalaloch"), hWA, TVI_SORT);
m_l.InsertItem(_T("Yakima"), hWA, TVI_SORT);
```

The question differently.

When I drag a control from the Toolbox and wooden I copy the code examples I gave are supposed to work or what needs to be done

Comment: Please show us what you have done, Please show us the code you have problems with...

Comment: What does the first call to InsertItem return? How is m_l defined?

Comment: What set I copied the example code into my code.

Comment: m_l Is the variable tree

Comment: What is the return value of the first IntertItem? m_l.m_hWnd is surely not NULL?

Comment: That's what you mean?
public:
 afx_msg void OnTvnSelchangedTree1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
 CTreeCtrl m_l

Comment: No. Set a breakpoint on the first InsertItem. Step over it, check the return value... My question should verify that the CTreeCtrl is correctly constructed or subclassed.

Comment: Where exactly in .cpp breakpoint or .h?

Comment: Doesn't matter...

Comment: Appreciate the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get it.
Need to boot in the "OnInitDialog" function [Like](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mfc/mfc_tree_control.htm) here.

I looked in the "OnInitDialog" classes view

Put name and initialization code works! thanks to all who helped!

My mistake.Press double click on the tree where I rebooted. CPP no in "OnInitDialog"

I wrote that if someone will mistakenly call him might help him. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent item to TVI_ROOT, not null. Also, from what I can tell, your code is only called when the selection in the tree changes; you'll probably want to do the whole InsertItem stuff in CMFCApplication67Dlg::OnInitDialog.

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: Appreciate the question.